# Word frequency over time : How to count the word frequency by date?

Tags: r, nlp, word-frequency

I have a data frame look like this :

| date | text |
| --- | --- |
| 201901 | Thank you for helping me |
| 201902 | You are amazing |
| 201902 | For helping with this |

My aim is to calculate the word frequency in each line, and eventually look like this:

| date | thank | you | for | helping | me | are | amazing | with | this | for |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 201901 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 201902 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

The actual data set is like this frame, but contains millions of text lines. So I was wondering how to automate this process using R, without typing all those texts lines.

Comment: Please pick one language/technology for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using R and tidyverse:**

```
df <- data.frame(date = c(201901, 201902, 201902),
                 text = c("Thank you for helping me", "You are amazing", "For helping with this"))

library(tidyverse)
```

**If you want your data as a table of counts**

```
df %>% 
            separate_rows(text, sep = " ") %>% 
            mutate(text = tolower(text)) %>% 
            table()
```

**Output:**

```
text
date     amazing are for helping me thank this with you
  201901       0   0   1       1  1     1    0    0   1
  201902       1   1   1       1  0     0    1    1   1
```

**If you want your output as a tibble**

```
df %>% 
        separate_rows(text, sep = " ") %>% 
        mutate(text = tolower(text)) %>% 
        table() %>% 
        as_tibble() %>% 
        pivot_wider(names_from = text, values_from = n)
```

**Output:**

```
# A tibble: 2 x 10
  date   amazing   are `for` helping    me thank  this  with   you
  <chr>    <int> <int> <int>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 201901       0     0     1       1     1     1     0     0     1
2 201902       1     1     1       1     0     0     1     1     1
```

**edit**: To transform everything to lowercase as your desired output and to show you the output

**edit2**: To show you that you can also get your data as a tibble to further work with it

Comment: Thank you bpvalderrama! It's been a great help!  I have over 1 million text lines, and i was wondering how to use one set of code to automate all of this. For example, instead of writing: text = c("Thank you for helping me", "You are amazing", "For helping with this") , i can just use the column name "text" to get all of the results.

Comment: Hi EconPug! Of course you can use the name of the column ("text" in your situation) to reproduce the code I shared with you.  The first two lines of codes I wrote were just to reproduce the dataset you are working with, and are not part of the analysis. I you were shared your data as text instead of images, then I wouldn´t written them. You can try with your own data in R if you wish :)

Comment: I'll look deeper into that,  Thank you very much!

Comment: For the future, it is better if you share a sample of your data along with your question instead of picture of how your data looks like. That makes things easier for us to show you some answers and for future people with your same question to test the answers with their own datasets

Comment: Sure! This is my first question, I haven't described the question clearly, I'll remember this and raise better questions in the future. Thank you very much bpvalderrama! Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)

df <- tibble(
  date = c("201901", "201902", "201902"),
  text = c("Thank you for helping me", 
           "You are amazing", 
           "For helping with this")
)

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  date   text                    
  <chr>  <chr>                   
1 201901 Thank you for helping me
2 201902 You are amazing         
3 201902 For helping with this

df %>%  
  unnest_tokens("words", text) %>% 
  group_by(date, words) %>% 
  summarise(count = n()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  spread(words, count)

# A tibble: 2 x 10
  date   amazing   are for helping    me thank  this  with   you
  <chr>    <int> <int> <int>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 201901      NA    NA     1       1     1     1    NA    NA     1
2 201902       1     1     1       1    NA    NA     1     1     1
```

Comment: Thank you Tom! The demo i show is only an example, but i have text data about  6GB, which contains over 1 million lines. I was wondering how to use one set of code to automate all of this. For example, instead of writing:  text = c("Thank you for helping me", 
           "You are amazing", 
           "For helping with this")
)
, i can just use the column name "text" to get all of the results.